# Immigration at 1st point of entry into Canada?

Tags: transit, canada

A passenger is travelling from Kuala Lumpur to Charlottetown (YYG) via NARITA and MONTREAL. Boarding card and baggage tag is given up to YYG. Does he go through immigration in the first port of entry to Canada (Montreal) or the final destination, Charlottetown in PEI?

Answer (score 4):

The flight from Montreal to Charlottetown is domestic, therefore you will go through immigration in Montreal. You will do that when moving from the international area to the domestic area of the airport.